# Show specific part of ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

I need a little help with getting the specific part of list view based on current time.I have a list view with times as string like : `"09:30"` - `"10:00"` - `"10:45"`.I'm using digital clock to show the current time in one activity and I want to show specific part of that listview based on current time. Example :

It's `10:30` and I want to show the list view items which are bigger than `10:30` like : `10:45`, `10:55` and etc.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate more clearly, what you are trying to do

Comment: I have listview with time as items and I want to show different items depending on current time.

Comment: Why not just call setPosition(int pos) on the listview where pos corresponds to the position with the current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're maintaining your data. Suppose each item is in a `Time` object that implements the `Comparable` interface, and you have `List<Time>` with all your data. Also, assume that the `ListView` is populated with an `ArrayAdapter` backed by a `Time[]` which you build from your `List<Time>`. (In MVC terminology, the `List<Time>` would be your model, the `ListView` would be the view, and your `Activity` class would be the controller.)

The following code could be used to populate the `ListView` with data:

```
private void updateTimes(List<Time> list) {
    Time[] times = new Time[list.size()];
    list.toArray(times);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Time>(this, R.layout.listitem, times));
}
```

When you wanted to filter the list to only show times after 10:30 (or any other time), you could do this (suppose `List<Time> mAllTimes` is the master list of times, and the `Time` class has a constructor that takes a `String`):

```
private void filterTime(String onOrAfter) {
    Time time = new Time(onOrAfter);
    List<Time> filtered = new ArrayList<Time>();
    for (Time t : mAllTimes) {
        if (t.compareTo(time) >= 0) {
            filtered.add(t);
        }
    }
    updateTimes(filtered);
}
```

Calling `filterTime("10:30")` would limit the list to only times on or after 10:30. Calling `updateTimes(mAllTimes)` would show the complete, unfiltered list.